# Display elements in different columns

Tags: python, tkinter

I Want to place those two elements in different extremes of my window, so, the label will be placed on the left and the button in the right, as in the image below
[image]

I tried different styles of layout management, as pack and Grid, but cannot solve my problem.

main.py

```
from faces.schedules import Schedules

from faces.App import App


app = App()  
schedules = Schedules(app)
app.mainloop()
```

Tkinter Window (app.py)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.app_width = 800
        self.app_height = 600
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        self.title('Backup Manager')
        self.iconbitmap('images/icon.ico')
        #dimensoes
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.geometry(newGeometry=f'{self.app_width}x{self.app_height}')
        self.style = ttk.Style(self)
        self.style.theme_use('xpnative')
```

Schedules.py

```
from tkinter.ttk import Button, Label, Frame

class Schedules(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupPage()


    def setupPage(self):
        self.header = Frame(self)
        self.title = Label(self.header, text="Meus agendamentos")
        self.setPageButton = Button(self.header, text='Mudar')
        self.gridElements()

    def gridElements(self):
        self.header.grid(sticky='we')
        self.title.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='W') 
        self.setPageButton.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky= 'E')         
        self.grid()
```

Comment: Did you try `.columnconfigure(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using weighted columns with `columnconfigure()`

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.columnconfigure(1, weight = 2) # Configures column 1 to function as 2 columns
tk.Button(root, text = "Left") .grid(row = 0, column = 0)
tk.Button(root, text = "Right") .grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = tk.E)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: It works, but how would I put all of this in a frame container? I'm asking because I want to set the visibility of all these elements at once in the future.

Comment: you can use .columnconfigure on Frame objects as well, it works just the same.

Answer (score 1):

For your case, I would suggest using `.pack()` instead of `.grid()`:

##### main.py

```py
from faces.schedules import Schedules
from faces.app import App

app = App()
schedules = Schedules(app)
schedules.pack(fill='x')
app.mainloop()
```

##### schedules.py

```py
from tkinter.ttk import Button, Label, Frame

class Schedules(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.setupPage()

    def setupPage(self):
        self.header = Frame(self)
        self.title = Label(self.header, text="Meus agendamentos")
        self.setPageButton = Button(self.header, text='Mudar')
        self.packElements()

    def packElements(self):
        # use pack() instead of grid()
        self.header.pack(fill='x')
        self.title.pack(side='left') 
        self.setPageButton.pack(side='right')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually placing it with .place? I use something like this:

```
self.setPageButton = Button(self.header, text="Meus agendamentos", command='What this button does if pressed').place(x = x-coord, y = y-coord) here
```

Since your app window is 800x600, you might want to try placing the button at (x = 780, y = 0 and moving it by experimentation. It's been a while since I've used tkinter, so not sure how well it might work.

Comment: I would highly recommend not using .place() accept for in very specific and specialized programs; Unless done correctly, can lead to very inflexible GUIS

Comment: I'm not the best at tkinter so you're probably right, but so far I've never had a problem with it and it's quite convenient for me.

Comment: You can use `relx` and `anchor` instead of *"moving it by experimentation"*.  Also `self.setPageButton` will be `None` in your code.